# UIImage memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimage

Can any one sort out my issue of memory leak in following code???

```
-(void)paint:(ImageWarper::WarpedImage *)warpedImg isCircleRequired:(bool)doDrawCircle atPoint:(CGPoint)pt{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
if(!mWarper) 
    return;
unsigned char *pixelData = warpedImg->Image.Data;
int imageHeight  = warpedImg->Image.Height;
int scanWidth = warpedImg->Image.ScanWidth;
int imageWidth = warpedImg->Image.Width;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(
                                                          NULL, 
                                                          pixelData, 
                                                          imageHeight * scanWidth, 
                                                          NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
int bytesPerPixel = warpedImg->Image.Bpp;
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth,
                                    imageHeight,
                                    BitsPerComponent,
                                    bytesPerPixel * BitsPerComponent,
                                    scanWidth,
                                    colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,
                                    NULL,
                                    YES,
                                    renderingIntent);

UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
//  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
imgScrollView.imgView.image = uiImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mbmpImage.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.5);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

[mbmpImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, mbmpImage.size.width, mbmpImage.size.height)]; 
[uiImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(warpedImg->Position.X, warpedImg->Position.Y, warpedImg->Image.Width, warpedImg->Image.Height)];         
[mbmpImage release];
mbmpImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
if(doDrawCircle){
    mbmpImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];           
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx,CGRectMake(pt.x - mRadius, pt.y - mRadius, mRadius*2, mRadius*2));
}
UIImage * resultingImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];    

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
imgScrollView.imgView.image =  resultingImage ;
if(!doDrawCircle)       
    mbmpImage = [resultingImage retain];

[resultingImage release];
[pool drain];
}
```

This function is called on touch events..

This is the snap of instrument where it shows leak..

[image]

Comment: maybe you are just passing retaining messages and giving these values to mbmpImage, but never releasing mbmpImage...try releasing it appropriately.

Comment: mbmpImage is class variable and I am using it every where

Comment: then you should be releasing that variable in dealloc section or either keep it in autorelease mode.

Comment: Ya I am releasing it in dealloc

Comment: okay, though not a totally trustable solution, but try checking the retain counts for that variable in the above method and also in the dealloc section, to know where it might be leaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[mbmpImage release];
mbmpImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
if(doDrawCircle){
    mbmpImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];           
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx,CGRectMake(pt.x - mRadius, pt.y - mRadius, mRadius*2, mRadius*2));
}
UIImage * resultingImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];    

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
imgScrollView.imgView.image =  resultingImage ;
if(!doDrawCircle)       
    mbmpImage = [resultingImage retain];

[resultingImage release];
[pool drain];
```

with

```
[mbmpImage release];
mbmpImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
if(doDrawCircle)
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx,CGRectMake(pt.x - mRadius, pt.y - mRadius, mRadius*2, mRadius*2));
UIImage * resultingImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];    

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
imgScrollView.imgView.image =  resultingImage ;
if(!doDrawCircle)
{
    [mbmpImage release];
    mbmpImage = [resultingImage retain];
}

[resultingImage release];
[pool drain];
```